# Checkstyle Issues In IntelliJIdea

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle

I have added the checkstyle plugins to take care of coding restriction. I fetched the checkstyle.xml from sonar cube server and added in plugin config. As shown :

When I try to check the current file. It shows me 3 warnings which actually should be errors. Moreover, On sonar server report there are 8 error. **Therefore I am missing 5 errors as well as there warning that are coming as warning should display as errors**. Any Idea how to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Checkstyle-IDEA plugin aims to match the results of the Checkstyle command line tool, not Sonar.

If your results differ from the command line tool then please raise an issue on the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea/issues). Otherwise, the likely cause is that the exported Checkstyle rules file does not match the Sonar configuration, which would be best raised with the Sonar team.

Comment: Also make sure that your Sonar and your IDEA use the same version of Checkstyle, and that you really see Checkstyle issues only. SonarQube runs other tools on your Java code as well, which also produce issues. Filter the SonarQube results by the `checkstyle` tag.